# Connection to DB2 through JDBC in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, jdbc, db2

I want to connect DB2 Database through JDBC in Shell Script on Linux Server

I have the jdbc details 
jdbc:db2://10.XXX.XXX.XX:/

I know we can connect using "Db2 Connect" command but DBA  is not recommending that. They are asking to use jdbc only.

Appreciate your help of you can point to any sample script.

thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

One way to script with jdbc only, is to use the IBM supplied [CLPPlus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html) command. That is a java application. It tries to emulate many of the functions of the Oracle SQL*Plus tool.  This is well explained in the Db2 Knowledge Center.

CLPPlus has some restrictions and may not be available in smaller footprint clients , refer to documentation.

However, almost all legacy Db2 environments use the regular `db2` command when scripting in shell , because it is the most secure, most flexible , most mature, and smallest footprint tool for that purpose. But it is native code (C/C++) and not java.  So you should ask that DBA to explain the rationale for not recommending that method.

Answer (score 0):

There's also `jsqsh`  https://github.com/scgray/jsqsh/wiki which can connect to any JDBC endpoint. It's endorsed by IBM  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bsql_jsqsh.html